# process has died Rplidar node

Tags: usb, rplidar

I'm using the ros2humble version, and I'm using rplidar A2m8.

The sbc is connected to Arduino and rplidar.
Using lsusb, it was confirmed that USB 0 is aruduino and USB 1 is rplidar. And when I ran rplidar node, it was confirmed that the process was dead.

[image]

[image]

this is my rplidar launch file

```
import os
from launch import LaunchDescription
from launch_ros.actions import Node

def generate_launch_description():

    return LaunchDescription([

    Node(
        package='rplidar_ros',
        executable='rplidar_composition',
        output='screen',
        parameters=[{
            'serial_port': '/dev/serial/by-path/platform-fd500000.pcie-pci-0000:01:00.0-usb-0:1.3:1.0-port0',
            'frame_id': 'laser_frame',
            'angle_compensate': True,
            'scan_mode': 'Standard'
        }]
       )
     ])
```

my lidar board rate is 115200

I'm not sure about the solution.
How should we resolve this?

Comment: Welcome to Robotics Stack Exchange! This may help: https://github.com/Slamtec/rplidar_ros/issues/63

Comment: I've tried following the solution of all GitHub's issues.
Chmod gave 666 and 777,
I even tried changing the bad rate. Now it's 256000.
I also changed the cable.
But nothing has changed. How do we solve it?